# How can I add a different Git diff tool for PDF?

Tags: git, pdf

I currently use `meld` as a Git diff tool. This works great, but I also have some PDF files under version control. Always when I make `git diff` I get ugly messages that inform me, that meld can't compare those binary files.

Today, I've found `diffpdf` which works great. But how can I configure git to use diffpdf for PDF (and only for them)?

I've configured git to use meld like this:

1. Create a script called `git-meld`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   meld "$2" "$5"
   ```
2. Make it executable: `chmod +x git-meld`
3. Add it to my config file: `git config --global diff.external git-meld`

But obviously I can't simply adapt this way to use both, diffpdf and meld.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to look at the `gitattributes` manual page. Basically, you create an external diff driver that specifies a custom command to use for comparing a specific type of file (this goes in `~/.gitconfig` or `${PROJECT}/.git/config`):

```
[diff "pdfdiff"]
    command = diffpdf
```

Then you specify that certain types of files use that diff driver (in `${PROJECT}/.gitattributes` or `{PROJECT}/some/subdir/.gitattributes`):

```
*.pdf diff=pdfdiff
```

Then everything except pdf files will use your normal `git diff` defaults, but pdf files will call `diffpdf` when you `git diff` them...

Comment: +1, this is almost what I wanted. Can I specify global that I want pdfs to be compared with pdfdiff? (instead of only project wide)

Comment: For "global" for a single user, there is the `core.attributesfile` config option that specifies a file that will apply to all projects that user works on (it's specified in your `~/.gitconfig` file). For "global" at a system scope, there's `/etc/gitattributes` (assuming you're using a distro-provided `git` version - it might be `/usr/local/etc/gitattributes` or something if you roll your own. That's all documented in the top part of `git help gitattributes`.

Comment: Thank you! (Don't you want to put the comment into your answer?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git difftool` ([man git difftool](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool.html)).

```
$ git difftool #opens in the tool defined in config: git config --get diff.tool
$ git difftool --tool meld # Opens in meld, regardless of what you configured.
$ git difftool --tool diffpdf # Opens in diffpdf.
```