How to realize a diff for pdf both visually helpful and integrating with git?
I would like to have a diff functionality for PDF files.
The requirements are integration with git and visual notion of difference.
Integrating with git means checking in text files.
I came across qpdf which is able to (de)compress PDF and to convert from and to JSON.
Roughly speaking, my notion is that in git I define a 'clean filter' converting to JSON,
like so:
qpdf --json-output --json-stream-data=inline xxx.pdf xxx.json

and a 'smudge filter'
qpdf --json-input --deterministic-id xxx.json xxx.pdf

Although the PDF files look the same, in fact, metadata changes.
Thus I added --deterministic-id.
I would expect that except the trailer ID, a file checked in and out
is the same as the original one.
This seems not the case.
I have regression tests for PDF creators which are broken.
My idea is now to create a special diff tool, say diffpdf.
Documentation of qpdf promises idempotence,
i.e. if apply qpdf twice with --deterministic-id nothing changes.
At the end, I want to compare JSON.
I experimented with a shell script
#!/bin/sh -
#!/bin/sh -
diff <(qpdf  --deterministic-id $1 - | qpdf --json-output --json-stream-data=inline) \
     <(qpdf  --deterministic-id $2 - | qpdf --json-output --json-stream-data=inline)

but I am not an able shell programmer and I have problems with qpdf.
Also I think naive diff of JSON is not the right thing;
it must be a diff tool ignoring certain equivalences in JSON files.
Maybe my concept is not sensible or my realization is bad.
I wonder also why qpdf changes trailer ID just converting to JSON and back to PDF.
At the end, I would like to integrate my diff tool also into git.

I don't think you should use clean/smudge filters. Just use diff filter. Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19639451/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+diff+pdf

Hm. I think this has two aspects: first diffing sensibly. Your solution adresses this.
Second: avoid checkin of binaries. Thats not with your solution.
Did you vote down my question? Because of this?

At all: how can I improve that this question meets the guidelines? I want to do.

I only answered about diff. I didn't try to avoid checking in binaries. I am not afraid of infrequently changing binaries (and frequently changed shouldn't be committed at all). If you want to preserve the original binary exactly you really should commit the binary not trying to subvert 3rd-party external tools which could change their behavior at any moment. None of the (currently) 3 downvotes are mine so I don't have an idea what's wrong and how to improve; for me the question is good enough in its current form.

Hmm Every alteration of a PDF will be different and I mean not just its ID which as its personal trackability (Fingerprint) SHOULD ALWAYS be changed but is often not ! if 2 PDFs are binary identical there is no difference (except how a viewer changes them). The best comparison is to do what the readers do and convert them to paper or phosphor pixels that way there is a measurable difference per page. There is of curse the possibility to export all plain text from a page too and then compare the textports, but will not show changes in rendering. There are many pdf image differs apps
